# Importing a module from a relative path

Tags: python, python-import

I have searched and not found a good answer. I have something very simple:

```
src/image.py
test/test.py
```

test.py is intended to test image.py so it needs to import it. It would seem logical that one would simply do

```
import ../src/image
```

or

```
import ..src.image
```

or

```
from ..src import image
```

But none of those work. When I search the forum I get lots of complicated answers, some of which require python to be started in a special mode to work. But why? It is just a file. The fact that it happens to be located in another directory, even one whose Linux path begins with .. should be irrelevant?

Please help me understand, and if there is a simpler way to do this, please help me find it ;-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Comment: The key is adding the containing directory to your `sys.path`, based on the script's location in `__file__`.  Once `src` is in the path, you can `import image`.

Comment: The latter two attempts would work if only you'd run Python from the parent directory of `test` and `src`.

Comment: That's just how the Python import system (unfortunately) works. It is not about "*It is just a file*" and whether it is following path convention for ".."

Comment: Thanks a lot for comments so far. The "billionth time" is interesting reading, and confusing reading. I am still chewing on it. It does seem to clarify that the path in an import doesn't refer to a path in the directory tree. It might do so by coincidence. Beyond that I don't yet understand it. As for using sys.path, I am doing that as a stop-gap, but the problem with it is that I can't specify where the file is. Instead I have to hope that it is the first one that python finds when it does the import (it was in this case).